# Help understanding the solver used in scipy spsolve and why its result is usually sparse

Tags: linear-algebra, python, sparse-matrices

In `scipy.sparse.linalg` package there is a solver called `spsolve` that solves

$$
AX = b 
$$

where $A,b$ are a sparse matrices.

[Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve.html) there is a claim being made that the result $X$ is often sparse, when $A$ and $b$ are very sparse.

However, from my understanding and experiments I did, the inverse of a sparse matrix $A$ is rarely ever sparse, and the product of a dense matrix with a sparse matrix may never be sparse. So how can we make the claim that $X$ is usually sparse?

My second question is concerning the solver used in `spsolve`. There is no literature reference on their webpage, so I am wondering if anyone knows the type of solver scipy uses, which would be helpful to understand under what conditions the result is sparse

Comment: Here’s a good book on the topic of direct methods for sparse linear systems: https://www.ebay.com/itm/185145831538

Comment: I’m also skeptical of the statement in the documentation that you mentioned.